# Table build homework html5

Tags: html

I have a homework, I tried to solve it and I'm not successful so I want to ask you for help, who could help me?

```
<table border="1">
      <caption>
      Waarnemeningen-
      <time id="nu"></time>
      <br>
      België
      </caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">Region</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Plaats</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Temp</th>
          <th colspan="2">Wind</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Snelhied</th>
          <th>Richting</th>
          <th>Druk / trend</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7SMo.jpg

Code: codepen.io/Kxamil/pen/wvvwPEN

this is how it should look like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgdFK.jpg

Comment: code
https://codepen.io/Kxamil/pen/wvvwPEN

Comment: Please update your question with the source code and the problems you have.

Comment: @luis.parravicini I can't because I'm writing that I have to write something more

Comment: @KxAmil That's right. You can't just dump your code into the question without any explanation. You have to write a description of your code when adding it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to read more about the rowspan and colspan which you can [find here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

and here's the code that match the given design

```
 <thead>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="2">Region</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Plaats</th>
              <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">Temp</th>
              <th colspan="3">wind</th>
              <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Druk / trend</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Druk / trend</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Snelhied</th>
              <th colspan="2">Richting</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
```

hope this help